# How to post on multiple friends wall using Graph api?

Tags: android

I have facebook ids of all my friends.So I just want to post (message and image)on their wall.

IS it possible to do this?

I posted on my wall by using the following code

```
 String res=     UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+Login.facebookid+"/feed?access_token="+accesstoken+"&method="+"post"+"&message="+strFullMessage.replaceAll(" ", "%20")+"&source="+imageUrl);
```

Can I use loop to post on multiple friends wall?

I read that doing this is a spam. Are there any apps doing this kind of requirement?

please help

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a subsequent delay of at least 3 seconds to use post method. you can achieve this by simply delaying you consecutive requests.

Comment: If I need to send to 100 friends,how much time this will take, and how can I prompt the user that process is going on.

Comment: I am using the same (message and image),is there any problem in doing this?

Comment: no there is no problem in sharing same image and message but to share on 100 friends wall will take 300 seconds :)

Comment: If you do this before,please send me the code for doing this.How to create a delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code for creating delay

first create a counter variable at class level

```
public int  counter = 0;
```

then use this code to create a repeatable counter

```
 final int postCount = 100;

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Send message here ;

        counter +=1;
        if(counter>=postCount){
            cancel();//stops the timer
        }


    }
}, 1000,3000);
```

the first parameter (1000) is the start delay (in ms)of timer and the second (3000) parameter is used to set subsequent delay between each repeat run actions.

Comment: I have an Arraylist of my friends facebook ids, can I run the loop in my run()

Comment: Yes you can iterate over the array list in the run method just use the `counter` value to get the current `index` item  of the array list

Comment: I tried this,it is working, but after 25 requests,I am getting Bad Request as Response and the posting cannot be done from there.Is there any Restriction after 25?

Comment: It did not tested it for more than 10 posts so may be there is a restriction of 25 posts :)

Comment: It can be also because of you have created to many HTTP IO connection. So use a `thread pool` and set the size to 10.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20980/discussion-between-user1891910-and-ali-imran)